# Starting Visual Studio debugger OpenCV

Tags: opencv, debugging, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to use Visual Studio for debugging a simple application that is making use of OpenCV.

I went through all the steps to build applications in Visual Studio as descriped in the [tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d6e/tutorial_windows_visual_studio_opencv.html). I can build the application in debug and release mode. Everything works fine as long as I start the application without debugging (debug->start without debugging). Yet, when I want to start debugging (debug->start debugging), I get the message:

> The code execution cannot proceed because opencv_world340d.dll was not found.

I am using Visual Studio 2017. I have set 'OPENCV_DIR' to '...\OpenCV\build\x64\vc15'.

Does anyone have a solution for this problem?

Comment: You need to have built and installed the debug version of opencv in order to link against it with your debug app. Have you?

Comment: I can find both the 'opencv_world340.dll' and the 'opencv_world340d.dll' in the bin folder.

Comment: Have you fixed it now?What I know is that even you set PATH env: %opencv_dir%\bin,vs still can't find it.One way to fix it is that putting opencv_world340d.dll in the same directory as your_execute file